# Gentoo Linux GPG encrypts properly a file passed through parameter but throws "Inappropriate ioctl for device" when reading from standard input

Tags: ssh, gentoo, gpg, gpg-agent

I am running Gentoo Hardened with kernel 4.1.7-hardened-r1 and I am trying to encrypt a file using GPG from a shell session opened from SSH and with the `DISPLAY` variable disabled in order to use pinentry-curses for password prompt. Using `gpg -o file.gpg --symmetric file` I can encrypt just fine. Using `pv file | gpg -o file.gpg --symmetric` I get the following error message:

```
gpg-agent[30745]: command get_passphrase failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You should set the `GPG_TTY` environment variable for it to work, as in [this document](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html):

```
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

Those two lines are supposed to be in your `~/.bashrc` (assuming bash), so they're run every time you open new terminal session.

There's another solution, though: in bash you can run your `pv` and pretend it's a file, using process substitution:

```
gpg -o file.gpg --symmetric <(pv file)
```

As such, it might not be a good idea to pipe-in things to programs that expect additional input. It can work differently than expected.

Comment: Is there any way to change or fix this behavior? Right now I just tried the exact same read-from-stdin command on Debian and GPG did ask for my password.

Comment: @RAKK Could you decrypt resulting file, though?

Comment: Yes, without a hitch on Debian. Create a little file with random data called `dsfargeg`, encrypt it with `pv dsfargeg | gpg -o dsfargeg.gpg --symmetric`, enter a password when prompted, decrypt the output with `gpg -o dsfargeg.gpg.dec --decrypt dsfargeg.gpg`, enter your password, and compare the original and the decrypted file with `sha256sum dsfargeg dsfargeg.gpg.dec`. Both hashes will be the same.

Comment: @RAKK You're right. It seems that gpg is opening `/dev/tty` on Debian. This was version 1.4, though, in my case; gpg got a bit of overhaul since. That approach might've been dropped for some reason - you might want to find out more on your own (or this can be some Debian specific patch). As such, it would be probably better for you not to count on it. I'll dig around in traces, to check what's exactly happening in newer gpg (I've got 2.1).

Comment: Strangely enough, [I've found a solution!](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html) Setting GPG_TTY variable does it for me. I'll update the answer accordingly.